# Use OneHotEncoder with specified set of values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a closed list of values I want to encode using OneHotEncoder. My problem is that the subset of values changes from one input to another and I want the encoding to be fixed.
I saw that OneHotEncoder has a "categories" parameter but couldn't get it to work. My code is below. Any suggestions?

`fit_transform` method throws the following exception:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories=pd.DataFrame({"type": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]}))
ct = ColumnTransformer([("encode_types", encoder, ["type"])])
X = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": [11, 22, 55],
    "type": ["A", "B", "D"], # in this examples C is missing
})

encoder.fit_transform(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should fit with the dataframe that you are now passing as catagories, namely:

```py
encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
encoder.fit(pd.DataFrame({"type": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]}))

X = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": [11, 22, 55],
    "type": ["A", "B", "D"], # in this examples C is missing
})

encoder.transform(X[['type']]).toarray()
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

And if we check the encoder categories we get:

```py
encoder.categories_
[array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype=object)]
```

Comment: I can't transform with the original, since I'm using this method to process many data frames, and some are missing some of the values. I need the output to be with the the columns (number and order)

Comment: @OriN you are not trasforming, you are fitting with it. As you can see from the result the order and indeces are as expected. You only need to make them into a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

### `get_dummies` with `reindex`

```
cats = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
pd.get_dummies(X.type).reindex(columns=cats, fill_value=0)

   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  0  1
```

---

#### `get_dummies` with `CategoricalDtype`

```
cats = pd.CategoricalDtype(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
pd.get_dummies(X.type.astype(cats))

   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: Thanks. I want the output to include all the columns from the original data sets (in my example col1). Is there a suggested way to do it?